# java script if condition with multiple values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I got a role from the back-end
If it is equals to **"admin"** , **"staff"**, **"manager"** it should go to the if part of the block. otherwise it should go to the else part of the block.

```js
let role = "restaurant";

if(role === "admin" || "manager" || "staff"){
  console.log("IF PART")
  console.log(role)
}
else{
  console.log("ELSE PART")
}
```

In this scenario it comes to if part. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `role === "admin" || role === "manager" || role === "staff"`

Comment: your code is like writing `if((role === "admin") || "manager" || "staff")` ... so that's `if (false || truthy || truthy)` - `false || truthy` is `truthy` - therefore IF PART

Comment: you could also `if (["admin", "manager", "staff"].includes(role))`

Comment: this has been asked so may times, even the "duplicate" as been marked as a duplicate of two answers, one of which is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate!! Guess the "search" function is hard to use

Comment: @JaromandaX there are total 4 nested duplicates

Comment: @Lokesh - isn't that what I said? or was I one short :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I think i am one short :P because there are two links in another duplicate question :D

Comment: as I said, asked soooo many times before :p

Comment: I usually choose duplicates that have duplicates to embarrass... I mean, so the duplicate can be more useful!

Comment: @undefined right. I also find it interesting when a question is marked as duplicate because it takes us to another question and contains more contents like in this problem. If we keep digging that's interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong, you are suppose to compare `role` variable with the role you want to check. As @lokesh mentioned in his code.

```
(role === "admin" || role === "manager" || role === "staff")
```

Another way of doing this:

```js
let role = "restaurant";
    
if(["admin", "manager", "staff"].includes(role)){
  console.log("IF PART")
  console.log(role)
}
else{
  console.log("ELSE PART")
}
```

`includes` available in majority of browsers for IE you can use `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrong. This should be like

```js
let role = "restaurant";

if(role === "admin" || role === "manager" || role === "staff"){
  console.log("IF PART")
  console.log(role)
}
else{
  console.log("ELSE PART")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can do more accurately as follows

```js
let role = "restaurant";

if (["admin", "manager", "staff"].indexOf(role.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
  console.log("IF PART")
  console.log(role)
} else {
  console.log("ELSE PART")
}
```